# Random column number set in one gridlayout

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## test.py

```
import sqlite3 as lite

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (600, 325)

class UserGroup(Screen):
    pass


class FactUserGroup(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FactUserGroup().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.120

UserGroup

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 20, 20
        row_default_height: '30dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Male'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id : chk


        Label:
            text: 'Female'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'age'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: age


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

[image]
(

How to set male,female in one row in same GridLayout.If i use two gridlaout first set cols: 4 and second set cols: 2 and show in pop up then it gives error "Popup can have only one widget as content".So how to set in one GridLayout with first row with 4 cols and second row 2 cols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with gridlayout alone.

You could make a gridlayout with two columns, and put horizontal boxlayouts in the grid you need to split.

Or you could use stacklayout. [stacklayout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.stacklayout.html)

I would just use two gridlayouts inside a vertical boxlayout.

You simply put both gridlayouts in a boxlayout. So the Popup will contain the boxlayout, and won't complain about multiple widgets.

```
MyBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    GridLayout1:
        cols: 2
    GridLayout2:
        cols: 4
```